# Have complication with Map?

Tags: java, arraylist

I have this question regarding generics.Can anybody explain me why the options 4 and 6[i know about this option]are correct?

Consider the following code:

```
import java.util.*;  
public class TestClass 
{  
    public static void main(String[] args)   
    {  
    // put declaration here      
    m.put("1", new ArrayList()); //1  
    m.put(1, new Object()); //2  
    m.put(1.0, "Hello");  //3  
    System.out.println(m);  
    }  
}
```

How can 'm' be declared such that the above code will compile and run without errors?

1. `Map m = new TreeMap();`
2. `Map<Object, Object> m = new TreeMap<Object, Object>();`
3. `Map<Object, ?> map = new LinkedHashMap<Object, Object>();`
4. `Map<Object, ? super ArrayList> m = new LinkedHashMap<Object, ArrayList>();`will work
    if lines //2 and //3 are commented out.
5. `Map<Object, ? super ArrayList> m = new LinkedHashMap<Object, ArrayList>();` will work if lines //1 and //3 are commented out.
6. `Map m = new HashMap();`

Comment: Options 1. and 2. are identical. Can you update them?

Comment: Have you tried to code and compile yourself? And what is the difference between options 1 and 2?

Comment: Option 2 is 2.Map<Object, Object> m = new TreeMap<Object, Object>();

Comment: So can you, please, modify the post?

Comment: I write the option 2 is in a correct manner.But it show like this.I don't know why?

Comment: Anything involving angle brackets needs to be quoted with backticks otherwise browsers will treat it as unknown HTML/XML tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For understanding this problem, look at the generic signature of the [`Map#put`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#put%28K,%20V%29) method you are using here. It states:

```
V put(K key, V value)
```

what means that you can put a key that is assignable to the generic type of the `Map`'s key type `K` and a value that is assignable to the generic type of the `Map`'s value type `V`. This must be true for all your key-value pairs you put into the map. From your code, you are putting the following keys into the map:

1. A `String` by the literal `"1"`
2. An `Integer` by the boxed `int` literal `1`.
3. A `Double` by the boxed `double` literal `1.0`.

The only common super type of these objects is the `Object` type which is required for `K` in order to allow all these objects to be used as a key.

For the values you have:

1. A `ArrayList` instance.
2. An `Object` instance
3. A `String` by the literal `"Hello"`

Again, the only common super type of these objects is the `Object` type which is required for `V` in order to allow all these objects to be used as a map value.

As a result, only `Map` instances with the generic signature `Map<Object, Object>` are permitted. What implementation of the `Map` interface you choose is up to you, as long as it is [assignable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/subtype.html) to the variable type of the map, i.e. you can use a `LinkedHashMap`, a `TreeMap` or a `HashMap` since they only differ in the way they store their data. For the generic type of the variables, note that the use of wildcards `?` or `? extends ...` for your variable will result in you not being able to put values into the map anymore. The tutorial I linked explains why.

As for the types with a non-generic signature you are using, they behave similar to `Map`s with the generic signature `<Object, Object>`. Such raw types should however [not longer be used after the introduction of Java 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it).

With all this information, you can answer your (exam) question yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Number 4 is correct for line 1, because "1" is String which has Object superclass and `? super ArrayList` means that you can use ArrayList or any superclass of ArrayList.

Number 6 is correct because you are using untyped(raw) map, so it's similar to:

```
Map<Object, Object> m = new HashMap<Object, Object>();
```

To store such values you can use Map, but it's not a really good choice. You shouldn't use untyped collections at all. Think how you can change your design to not use such map.

Comment: "...or any superclass of ArrayList." I'm sure you meant any subclass here.

Comment: @user3301492 please read about lower bounded wildcards
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/lowerBounded.html

Comment: @user3301492 It's indeed the superclass, as indicated by the **super** keyword. BTW: Although raw types are "similar" to types parameterized with `<Object...>`, there are subtle differences. Simply said: In the latter case, the types are checked for consistency, whereas with raw types there is no check at all

Comment: Then why  when using a superclass AbstractList list = new ArrayList(); m.put("1", list); is causing an Error "type Map<Object,capture#1-of ? super ArrayList> is not applicable for the arguments (String, AbstractList)"?

Comment: @user3301492 it's because you instantiated Map as a HashMap<Object, ArrayList> and then you can only pass ArrayList as a value.